# find columns closest to centroids - Pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["State",       "Adult", "Senior","Children"]) 
df.loc[0]             = ["California",     111,    2,       6    ] 
df.loc[1]             = ["Texas",          70,     2,       4    ] 
df.loc[2]             = ["Florida",        64,     4,       5    ] 
df.loc[3]             = ["Georgia",        25,     2,       3    ] 
df.loc[4]             = ["Alaska",         90,     1,       2    ] 
df.loc[5]             = ["Hawaii",         105,    2,       1    ] 
df.loc[6]             = ["Washington",     27,     3,       2    ] 
df.loc[7]             = ["Pennsylvania",   90,     2,       1    ] 
df.loc[8]             = ["Virginia",       63,     2,       3    ] 
df.loc[9]             = ["Arizona",        34,     2,       4    ] 
df.loc[10]            = ["Michigan",       22,     5,       2    ] 
 
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4) 
y = kmeans.fit_predict(df[['Adult', 'Senior', 'Children']]) 
df['Cluster'] = y 
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_ 
plt.scatter(df.Adult, df.Senior, c=df.Cluster) 
plt.scatter(centers[:,0],centers[:,1],color='black',marker='*',label='centroid')
plt.show()
```

For the Kmeans analysis broken out by state above, I would like to extract/identify elements out of each cluster, which are the closest to that cluster's centroid.

Comment: Welcome to SO Code_starter! Do you want to extract the "closest point" to each cluster center? Or do you want to add an additional column to `df` representing the cluster?

Comment: want to find out  2 points that are closest to a cluster center provided there are 2 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically: the [`KMeans`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) implementation is based on Euclidean distance. To get the two closest points to each centroid we can look at the set of points that belong to each cluster, take the 2-norm of the difference between the relevant centroid, and return the two closest points:

```py
def get_2_closest(cluster_id, df, columns, centers):
    current = df[df["Cluster"] == cluster_id][columns]
    closest = np.argsort(
        np.linalg.norm(current.to_numpy(dtype=np.float64) - centers[cluster_id], axis=1)
    )
    return current.iloc[closest[:2]]
```

Full example in context:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["State",       "Adult", "Senior","Children"])
df.loc[0]             = ["California",     111,    2,       6    ]
df.loc[1]             = ["Texas",          70,     2,       4    ]
df.loc[2]             = ["Florida",        64,     4,       5    ]
df.loc[3]             = ["Georgia",        25,     2,       3    ]
df.loc[4]             = ["Alaska",         90,     1,       2    ]
df.loc[5]             = ["Hawaii",         105,    2,       1    ]
df.loc[6]             = ["Washington",     27,     3,       2    ]
df.loc[7]             = ["Pennsylvania",   90,     2,       1    ]
df.loc[8]             = ["Virginia",       63,     2,       3    ]
df.loc[9]             = ["Arizona",        34,     2,       4    ]
df.loc[10]            = ["Michigan",       22,     5,       2    ]

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
y = kmeans.fit_predict(df[["Adult", "Senior", "Children"]])
df["Cluster"] = y
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_


def get_2_closest(cluster_id, df, columns, centers):
    current = df[df["Cluster"] == cluster_id][columns]
    closest = np.argsort(
        np.linalg.norm(current.to_numpy(dtype=np.float64) - centers[cluster_id], axis=1)
    )
    return current.iloc[closest[:2]]


_closest = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Adult', "Senior", "Children"])

for i in range(len(centers)):
    output = get_2_closest(i, df, ["Adult", "Senior", "Children"], kmeans.cluster_centers_)
    _closest = _closest.append(output)

plt.scatter(df.Adult, df.Senior, label="Original")
plt.scatter(_closest.Adult, _closest.Senior, label="2 Closest to Centroid")
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], color="black", marker="*", label="centroid")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Expected output:

[image: Graph showing all points, their centroids, and the two closest points to each centroid.]

Question raised in comment: you can get the `State` column back by merging the two data frames:

```py
print(
  _closest.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True)['State']
)
```

Output:

```
4          Alaska
7    Pennsylvania
6      Washington
3         Georgia
2         Florida
8        Virginia
0      California
5          Hawaii
```